# ASP.NET Core DI inside a singleton class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a **SvcPool** class which registers as a singleton service,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<SvcPool, SvcPool>();
}
```

**SvcPool** will initialize several **Svc** based on config inside constructor,
but the Svc class constructor need a ILogger.

How to DI a **ILogger** to Svc's constructor?

Svc.cs

```
public Svc(int id, string host, ILogger<Svc> logger)
{
    ...
}
```

SvcPool.cs

```
public SvcPool(IOptions<AppConfig> config, ILogger<SvcPool> logger)
{
    foreach (var svcConfig in config.SvcList)
    {
        Svc svc = new Svc(svcConfig.ID, svcConfig.Host, ???);
    }        
}
```

Comment: You need to register a logger in the service collection.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1.

Comment: I did. Logging is fine inside the SvcPool, the problem is how to pass ILogging<Svc> when new Svc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have three options. I've ordered them in the order that I think is best->worst, but use the one that works for you.

1 - Create a factory for Svc:

```
services.AddSingleton<Svc.Factory>(svcProvider => (id, host) => new Svc(id, host, svcProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Svc>>()));

public class Svc
{
    public delegate Svc Factory(int id, string host);

    public Svc(int id, string host, ILogger<Svc> logger)
    {

    }
}

public SvcPool(IOptions<AppConfig> config, ILogger<SvcPool> logger, Svc.Factory serviceFactory)
{
    foreach (var svcConfig in config.SvcList)
    {
        Svc svc = serviceFactory(svcConfig.ID, svcConfig.Host);
    }
}
```

2 - Register a factory which you can inject into `SvcPool` as `Func<ILogger<Svc>>`:

```
services.AddSingleton<Func<ILogger<Svc>>(svcProvider => () => svcProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Svc>>());

public SvcPool(IOptions<AppConfig> config, ILogger<SvcPool> logger, Func<ILogger<Svc>> loggerFactory)
{
    foreach (var svcConfig in config.SvcList)
    {
        Svc svc = new Svc(svcConfig.ID, svcConfig.Host, loggerFactory());
    } 
}
```

3 - Inject `IServiceProvider` into `SvcPool`, and use the service locator anti-pattern to resolve a new instance of `ILogger<svc>`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ILoggerFactory` and create `ILogger` instances when instantiating `Svc`.

```
public SvcPool(IOptions<AppConfig> config, ILogger<SvcPool> logger, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    foreach (var svcConfig in config.Value.SvcList)
    {
        Svc svc = new Svc(svcConfig.ID, svcConfig.Host, loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Svc>());
    }
}
```